# Unexpected token with curly braces in ES6?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I am trying to create a "get image url" function in my react.js component, but for some reason it keeps telling me that there is an unexpected token when the function's curly braces are necessary:

```
// Loading.js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Header extends Component {

render() {
  const data = this.props.data
  const header_data = data.globals.header

  getImageURL(data) {
      if(header_data) {
        var logo_image_url = _.findWhere(metafields, { key: 'logo-image' }).url;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }

    const logo_image_url = data.globals.header.logo_image.url;

      return (
        <div id="siteHeader">
          <img className='logo' width="300" src="{logo_image_url}"/>
          <span>The Heading!</span>
        </div>
      );
    }
}

  export default Header;


This is the error I get:

 Unexpected token (9:20)
   7 |   const data = this.props.data
   8 |   const header_data = data.globals.header
>  9 |   getImageURL(data) {
     |                     ^
  10 |       if(header_data) {
```

There are no extra curly braces, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That syntax is only valid when you are declaring class methods.

You can use instead

1º

```
function getImageURL(data) {
      if(header_data) {
        var logo_image_url = _.findWhere(metafields, { key: 'logo-image' }).url;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
 }
```

2º

```
const getImageURL = function(data){
    if(header_data) {
        var logo_image_url = _.findWhere(metafields, { key: 'logo-image' }).url;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
}
```

3º

```
const getImageURL = (data) => {
    if(header_data) {
        var logo_image_url = _.findWhere(metafields, { key: 'logo-image' }).url;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
}
```

Or you can declare it outside the render method.

```
class Header extends React.Component {
    getImageURL(data){
        if(header_data) {
            var logo_image_url = _.findWhere(metafields, { key: 'logo-image' }).url;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    render(){...}
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/631/)